# change .php extension to .php5

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to create an php file with extension .php5. I am using apache 2.2 and php 5.5.3 in my system , tried editing the configuration file by adding

**Action application/x-httpd-php .php5** but still no use

Comment: What do you mean trying to create a file? Did you name the file that way? What's the problem?

Comment: basically I need to create a php file with the name "home.php5" which would display some php content in it

Comment: What part of that process is not working? Creating the file is surely the easy step. Is there any reason for `.php5`? PHP 7 is out and PHP 4 is the only reason files were ever called `.php5` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from my php conf file:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

And I can run `myfile.php5` as php as long as that is what the file is named. Put it in your php conf or if your lazy your `.htaccess` file